# Maximum notification rate for G-suite Admin SDK APIs

Tags: push-notification, google-api, google-admin-sdk

I am building an app to receive push notifications for drive activity changes using `G-suite Reports API`. If there are 1K users and assume each of them creates (1 create event + 1 edit event)/sec, how many notifications can I expect to receive from G-suite?

The `Guide`(https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/push) states certain lag in sending notifications, but is there any limit on how many notifications it can send per second per resource similar to Gmail API push notifications(https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push)?

Comment: I think it does not work like that; new events are only recognized after some time and events get accumulated. I have never seen it written but I guess there is a hard limit of notifications per day or hour.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific limit on this, but on [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/limits) there is a limit on Queries per second QPS and on Queries per day QPD:

> The API limits the number of requests for your APIs Console project. The API project's maximum number of requests per second (project QPS) is 5 QPS. And, the maximum number of requests per day (project QPD) is 150,000 QPD across the account.
> If these limits are exceeded, the server returns an HTTP 503 status code. Use the exponential backoff algorithm when retrying your requests.

Also, there is a [Data retention and lag times](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7061566) regarding Admin console reports and audit logs